# Getting Started with EF Core on ASP.NET Core with an Existing Database

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am trying to connect my web api to an existing database using this command by going in `tools-> nuget package manager -> nuget package manager console`

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

But it says

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

It's supposed to get all tables from this database and show them in models, I've done this before and forgotten the procedure, I'm just trying to connect it to database first so I an copy the rest of the code and get the API working

Comment: Make sure your mysql server is up and running that is the issue.

Comment: yea, its working fine, stackoverflow isnt letting me upload a picture so i could show you the server is working fine and ive created a database and added tables in it

Comment: this is a connectivity issue. instead of (localdb) why dont you put the name of the server like PC43443/SQLServer or something like that.

Comment: Scaffold-DbContext "Server=DESKTOP-217V7PT;Database=AptitudeTest;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models

Comment: you need the name of the sql server installed so it would be DESKTOP-217V7PT/servername

Comment: after closing it and opening again for several times it worked, like it got all the models but api isnt working, like its connected to database but wont show anything(won't get any data from db not even values 'value1 and value2' that it shows when an empty api is run), a few days ago i was trying to free up space in c drive i might have uninstalled some component or something, is there any way i can find out what component is missing?